# Which cache system is better for mondrian SegmentCache

Tags: mondrian

Which cache system is better for mondrian SegmentCache?
Memcached, Redis, Hazelcast or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Not so much because it's better, but because setting it up is simpler, the Community Distributed Cache uses Hazelcast to create a cluster of cache nodes which keep results in memory. From previous experience I think it works quite nicely and it's very easy to set up. You can find the CDC plugin in the Pentaho Marketplace or on github: https://github.com/webdetails/cdc